# Ram allocated in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed VirtualBox and also want to run it, but when I want to create kali Linux max based ram memory allocated it only 6GB, how do I change it?. can it change to higher more than 6GB? I watch it can reach higher than mine. I need your help. I put my virtual box screenshot to

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and indicate how much system memory you have

Comment: i have 8gb ram in my computer

Comment: You should edit your question  and provide that information.  However, it appears this is an intentional design choice of VirtualBox, to limit the amount of memory you can assign to the virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox uses real, physical memory, which is your host computer's RAM.  That dialog box shows the maximum amount of memory in your host computer, so you cannot exceed that amount.  If you need to assign more memory to your virtual machine, you will need to add more physical memory to your host machine.

Comment: what should i do to improve it?

Comment: @ryand "what should i do to improve it?" Improve what?

Comment: @ryand if you own this computer, then research the appropriate kind of RAM to buy, and watch some YouTube videos on how to install or replace RAM.  If it's a school computer, ask the teacher or other authority if they are willing to upgrade or if there's another with more RAM available.